# XDebug only works on localhost and not remote host

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi3, xdebug

I've installed xdebug on my raspberry pi with visual studio code and everything is working except that I can't use xdebug with a remote host.

In php.ini and xdebug.ini and php.ini I have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` however whenever I load the page from my personal computer I just get `listening for xdebug` in vs code.

this is my configuration in php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

and this is my configuration in xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

It should work when I open the webpage on my computer but nothing happens. And there isn't even a log file in /tmp/.

Comment: xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log.. I'm sure you would have taken a look at the log file. other than that hope your code works. I worked with xdebug, although not for remote debugging and it worked well. thanks n good luck.